# Import Error partially initialized from imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i dont know how i can call function from the file who import.

**toolkit.py**:

```
from utilities import bcolors, utility
from backups import backups
import os
version = "1.0"

utility.UpdateNeeded()

class main():
    def main():
        print( bcolors.BOLD + "Toolkit" + bcolors.ENDC)

        print("")
        choose = int(input(bcolors.BOLD + "1"  + ": " + bcolors.CYELLOW + "Backups" + bcolors.ENDC + "\n\
"+bcolors.BOLD + "0"  + ": " + bcolors.CYELLOW + "Close" + bcolors.ENDC + "\n\
> "))
        if choose == 0:
            #exit
            print(bcolors.CGREEN + "Ciao." + bcolors.ENDC)
            exit()
        if choose == 1:
            #do magic
            os.system('cls')
            main.menu_backup()

    def menu_backup():
        choose = int(input(bcolors.BOLD + "1"  + ": " + bcolors.CYELLOW + "Check Backups" + bcolors.ENDC + "\n\
"+bcolors.BOLD + "0"  + ": " + bcolors.CYELLOW + "Main Menu" + bcolors.ENDC + "\n\
> "))
        if choose == 0:
            os.system('cls')
            main.main()
        if choose == 1:
            os.system('cls')
            backups.check_backups()

main.main()
```

**backups.py**:

```
from utilities import bcolors, utility
from toolkit import main


class backups:
    def __init__(self, my_dirs, my_files,           
                     curdir): 
        self.my_dirs = [] 
        self.my_files = [] 
        self.curdir = '' 

    def check_backups(ln):
        print(bcolors.CRED + "Check Backups..." + bcolors.ENDC)
        main.menu_backup()
```

**utilities.py**:

```
class bcolors:
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    CRED    = '\33[31m'
    CGREEN  = '\33[32m'
    CYELLOW = '\33[33m'

class utility:
    #def __init__(self):
    
    def UpdateNeeded():
        print("update check...")
```

that gives me following error:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'backups' from partially initialized module 'backups' (most likely due to a circular import)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toolkit.py` you are trying to import something from `backups.py`, but in `backups.py` you are trying to import something from `toolkit.py`. Python can't import the one without the other so it goes into a loop, detects it and gives you this error. You need to separate the two components so that they are not dependent on each other anymore.

Comment: okay. thank you. but how can i call a function ffrom toolkit.py then in backups.py i want that the menu get displayed again

Comment: Just call the menu_backup() function from within the main class again and remove the main.menu_backup() call and import main statement from backups.py. That way the backups.py isn't relying on any other functionality from the main class / toolkit.py